# How Can I Check SQL Statement is Success Executed in VB6

Tags: php, sql, vb6

I have these codes

```
Call Connection

Dim SQLInsert As String

SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO `Admin` (" & _
                "`kode`," & _
                "`nama`," & _
                "`password`," & _
                "`level`" & _
            ") VALUES (" & _
                "'" & Text1.Text & "', " & _
                "'" & Text2.Text & "', " & _
                "'" & Text3.Text & "', " & _
                "'" & Combo1.Text & "'" & _
            ")"

conn.Execute SQLInsert

MsgBox "Insert Succeed"
```

How can i get returned value from executing statement above, whether the code succeed or fail...

I want to get returned value like in PHP

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if ($result)
       //executing other code
```

How can i do like that in VB6? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be the possibility to get the 'rows effected' value back. Please read this Microsoft Link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559(v=vs.85).aspx

You will need to add the 'adExecuteNoRecords' option, chapter 'Remarks'

Answer (score 1):

Read about the [ON ERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx) statement. It allows to handle exceptions in VB.

```
Dim SQLInsert As String

ON ERROR GOTO ErrorHandler

SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO `Admin` (" & _
                "`kode`," & _
                "`nama`," & _
                "`password`," & _
                "`level`" & _
            ") VALUES (" & _
                "'" & Text1.Text & "', " & _
                "'" & Text2.Text & "', " & _
                "'" & Text3.Text & "', " & _
                "'" & Combo1.Text & "'" & _
            ")"

conn.Execute SQLInsert

MsgBox "Insert Succeed" 
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: 
 Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " &
        Err.Source & ControlChars.CrLf & Err.Description
  MsgBox(Msg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer my question. But how can i get returned value from sql statement like "SELECT COUNT()" or "SELECT MAX()"

Comment: With these queries you will be better off with the Ado.Recordset. Search google - there are plenty VB classic examples